# Handlebar.helper's view cannot use actions from controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, handlebars.js

How do I call an action that is inside a controller from a view that uses a handlebar helpers (not sure if the handlebar helper is relevant to getting the controller but I wanted to mention it anyway)?

```
VpcYeoman.EditRecordCategoryView = Ember.TextField.extend({
   //This is where i call the action from any controller
  click: function() { // might be a property or some other action
    this.get('controller').send('controllerActionName');  
  }
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('edit-recordCategory', VpcYeoman.EditRecordCategoryView);
```

What would I do inside of that view to tell a controller that I want it to activate one of its actions?

Edit 1:

I added `this.get('controller').send('controllerActionName');` to `click:function(){}`,
and I receive the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on that line of code.

If I add `this.get('controller').send('controllerActionName');` to didInsertElement: function(), i dont get any error at all.

Edit 2:

The handlebar helper is located in a list that uses an object controller named `recordType`. 'recordType' is where that action is that I'm  looking to call from the handlebar help's click event. However

in  record_types.hbs

```
{{#each itemController="recordType"}}
  {{#unless isEditing}}
     {{categoryName}} &nbsp;
  {{/unless}}
  {{#if isEditing}}
    {{edit-recordCategory class="edit" value=category_name focus-out="acceptChanges" insert-newline="acceptChanges"}} //This is the handlebar helper
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

We can assume that the `isEditing` property in the record is `true` since the handlebar helper will not be visible if it is `false`.

Actually the action in the controller of my project is meant to toggle that property `isEditing`.

Answer (score 1):

To call a controller action from its view you do this:

```
VpcYeoman.EditRecordCategoryView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  //This is where i call the action from any controller
  click: function() { // might be a property or some other action
    this.get('controller').send('controllerActionName');  
  }
});
```

Comment: im receiving the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` for that long. Is it possible that it doesn't know what controller im inside?

Comment: Not really, views will always have a controller as they default to the context where they are rendered. How are you rendering? What does your template look like?

Comment: Okay good because the object controller is set in the `{{#each}}` loop (also where that action i want is located). I updated the question for you (edit 2)

Comment: Looks fine, it should work, assuming that the controller that renders `record_types.hbs` is an `Ember.ArrayController`.

Comment: is there any way to use something like this.get('objectcontroller') or this.get('arraycontroller')?

Comment: Yes, just like in my answer: `this.get('controller')` will fetch the controller regardless of its type.